# Resizing table widget when window is maximized

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a simple pyqt UI in which there is a table widget. I want the widget to resize when I resize the main window. There is a similar question posted on stackOverflow ([Resizing table columns when window is maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143506/resizing-table-columns-when-window-is-maximized)), but the answers given do not solve my purpose. In particular I tried using`self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)`
. It resizes the column width of the table according to the table widget geometry but does not resize the widget itself when I resize the main window. I'm using pyqt5 and spyder IDE.

Here is an example

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(566, 475)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setWindowTitle("Transactional Data")
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 461, 381))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 566, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(566, 475)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setWindowTitle("Transactional Data")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']) 
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]